# Given the inputs and output for a function, I need to find the optimal coefficients

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Consider this function:

[image: Polynomial Function]

With `k1 ... k5` being the coefficients and k6 being another constant. The coefficients and the constants do not have any constraints. What would be a good way to optimize such a function? The inputs and outputs are available to me.

I was following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/get-started-with-tensorflow-2-0-and-linear-regression-29b5dbd65977) and using the given function as the hypothesis but that didn't help.

EDIT:
I do have a dataset of x1's, x2's....x5's, and y's.

Comment: You might want to start by defining what you consider optimal in this case.

Comment: You can use many optimization methods, such as [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), depending on your selection.

Comment: @RolandSmith by optimal I mean the right coefficients that will give the desired outputs. As mentioned in the post, the inputs (X1 .... X5) and the output Y is given to me. I also have a dataset of X's and Y's. What would be a way to fit the coefficients?

Comment: @J.Choi Thank you so much! I tried that method and it gave me a set of values for (k1...k5)! Now I will have to find methods to improve on this result.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more a question for a mathematician (which I'm not), but here we go.

Since you have six coefficients, and y and x1--x5 are known, there are *infinite* combinations that would work.

For example, if k1, k2 and k3 are zero, then k6 = y, and k4 and k5 can have *any* value.

On the other hand, it can be shown that k4*x4 != k5*x5, otherwise the fraction would become infinite.

If k2, k3 and k5 are 0, then the ratio of k1 to k4 determines k6.
And so on and so forth. If you choose 5 of the constants, the 6th follows.

**Edit**

In my reasoning above, I do not mention the x values. This is on purpose. If you think about the problem in a way that does not depend on specific values of x, the reasoning should be valid for all values of x.

So the values of the x and y do not matter (unless a given x is 0, in which case the corresponding k is irrelevant.)

Comment: I not only have one set of y and x1...x5 as known. I have a dataset of y's, x1's, x2's ...x5's. In this case what would be the best way to fit it for that dataset?

Comment: @ken Are you looking for a *single set* of k values that satisfy *all* the different set of x, y values? How many sets of x,y values do you have?

Comment: Smith. I have a dataset with about 800 x1's, 800 x2's, 800 x3's ... and so on. For each set of x1....x5, I have a y as well.